# Combine data from multiple .log files and reading them without creating new .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-writing

At the moment I have working code that can read multiple .log files and create a giant .txt file which contains all their data. Then I simply read the giant .txt file. However, this code is inefficient because it involves writing a new .txt file every time I want to run the script.

Does someone know how to simplify this so that it doesn't write a new .txt file every time? Ideally by creating a 'virtual' .txt file?

```matlab
files=dir('IndividualFiles.*.log');
fileout='GIANT.txt';
fout=fopen(fileout,'w');
for cntfiles=1:length(files)
  fin=fopen(files(cntfiles).name);
    temp = fread(fin,'uint8');
    fwrite(fout,temp,'uint8');
    fprintf(fout,'\n');
  fclose(fin);
end
fclose(fout);
filename = 'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Learning Documents\myfolder\GIANT.txt';
```

Comment: you have the data in `temp` and then write it in `fout`. You can just not write it, and store it as `temp{cntfiles}=...` if they are different size, or problably something like `temp(:,cntfiles)=...` if they are

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri I see what you mean. I should mention the next line of existing code converts the .txt into a table (using a function generated from the Import Data feature). 

         
myfunction(filename);

So ideally I want to store in memory a "virtual" .txt file, but I just don't want to write it anywhere. Thanks :)

Comment: a virtual txt is a variable! There is no such thing as virtual txt, just data, and data written in files in a human readable format e.g. a txt. If you have the data loaded you don't need to do anything else. Well, maybe some couple of codes to get it to your desired format, but that we can not help without an actual [mcve]

Comment: You're absolutely right. In my function that I've got following my code. I should change it so that it takes in a variable instead of a .txt file. Then I can use the variable created earlier and put that as an input into the function. Thanks :)

The first couple of lines of my function are:
1) output = myfunction(filename)
2) delimeter = {';','='};
3) formatSpec = '%s%s%s%s%s%s%[^\n\r]';
4) fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

I suspect I can solve this by replacing the input of the .txt file to the variable, and getting rid of the 4th line. Right? Thanks :)

Comment: This question is becoming quite different to the question I originally posted. So I thought I'd make a separate question. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688365/matlab-automatically-generated-function-to-input-a-variable-instead-of-a-txt-fi

Comment: I suggest you delete the other question, come to this one and [edit] it, I insist, with a [mcve]. Data is very different and complicated and we can not help without knowing how the data is stored. You need to create an full example that can be run by us without any assumptions from our side, or we can't help.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty approach would be `log_files = []; for % condition+reading; log_files = [log_files temp];` You'll get nice, orange wiggles underneath that last line, as growing a variable dynamically is rather bad for speed. This only works if all your `temp` files, i.e. your log files, have the same structure (which I presume they do, given the same read function).

Comment: @AnderBiguri regarding your first comment, I have stored data from each .log file as temp{cntfiles} like you suggested. Now how do I proceed? How can I turn this into a usable (non binary) variable without writing it to another file? Thanks so much :)

Comment: I will try to tell you last time: I can't help without a [mcve]. If I don't know whats in the data, I dont know whats in `temp{cntfles}` and I dont know how you want it to look. I could guess and almost certainly not get it right, or you could [edit] your post to add the required minimal example.