# MATLAB automatically generated function to input a variable instead of a .txt file

Tags: matlab, import

MATALB's "Import Data" feature automatically generates a function which inputs a .txt-file and outputs a table. The first few lines of this function looks like this:

```
function output= myfunction(filename)
delimiter = {';','='};

%% Read columns of data as text:
formatSpec = '%s%s%s%s%s%s%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string',  'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);
```

However, I need this function to input a variable instead of a .txt-file that will have the exact same effect. I have all the data stored in the .txt-file in the form of a variable already. I thought I could simply replace `filename` with the variable, and delete of the `fileID` and `fclose` lines of code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly you want

Comment: You can't omit `fopen` nor `fclose`, since you need to open a file first in order to read it. What you could do is move them outside the function, generate the fileID there, and pass that as a variable to the function. Don't forget to close the file after reading it! I don't see any merit in doing this this way though, keeping the `fopen/fclose`  syntax within the read function itself ensures that you don't have accidentally left-open files floating around.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what is in the variable you wish to parse? Ideally, you can generate a minimal, reproducible example of this variable (e.g. `myVariable=sprintf('1;2;3;4\n\r5;6;7;8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this auto-generated function in a loop to loop through the file(name)s that you have

```
% path to folder with txt-files
pFlr = pwd; % path to working directory
Lst = dir( fullfile(pFldr,'*.txt') ); % only get txt-files

for i = 1:length(Lst)
   % path to file
   pFl = fullfile( Lst(i).folder,Lst(i).name );
   % read file by calling the auto-generated function
   Dat1 = myfunction( pFl );
end
```

In this way, you can access all your files in a loop and, e.g. store the data in a table:

```
k = 1; % control variable
for i = 1:length(Lst)
   % path to file
   pFl = fullfile( Lst(i).folder,Lst(i).name );
   % read file by calling the auto-generated function
   Dat1 = myfunction( pFl );


   % do something with this data, e.g. store it
   if i == 1 % allocate data if
      Dat = Dat1;
      % extend for allocation
      vSz= height(Dat1)*length(Lst);
      Dat(vSz,:) = Dat1(1,:); % assign the first row of the first table to the last row of the allocated table to expand it
   else
      Dat(k:k+size(Dat1)-1,:) = Dat1;
   end
   k = k + size(Dat1);
end
% crop table
Dat = Dat(1:k-1,:);
```